# Filling multiple "forms" per Google doc page with records from a Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google sheet as data source. I want to fill 1 google doc and each page of the doc has 4 templates/forms.  Fields1, Fields2, etc.  I have it working for the first 4 records in the sheet (one page), but how do I dynamically extend to another page and 4 more templates and have it keep going?

```
function onOpen() {
    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    const menu = ui.createMenu('Auto Fill');
    menu.addItem('Create Delivery Slips', 'createNewDeliverySlips');
    menu.addToUi();
}

function createNewDeliverySlips() {
    const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('<id>');
    const googleDocFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('<id>');
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`Delivery Slips`, googleDocFolder);
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById( copy.getId() );
    const body = doc.getBody();

    rows.forEach( function( row, index ) {
        if (index === 0) return;

        if (index % 4 === 1){
            body.replaceText('{{First Name1}}', row[1]);
            body.replaceText('{{Last Name1}}', row[2]);
            body.replaceText('{{Address1}}', row[3]);
            body.replaceText('{{City1}}', row[4]);
            body.replaceText('{{State1}}', row[5]);
            body.replaceText('{{Zip1}}', row[6]);
        }

        if (index % 4 === 2){
            body.replaceText('{{First Name2}}', row[1]);
            body.replaceText('{{Last Name2}}', row[2]);
            body.replaceText('{{Address2}}', row[3]);
            body.replaceText('{{City2}}', row[4]);
            body.replaceText('{{State2}}', row[5]);
            body.replaceText('{{Zip2}}', row[6]);
        }

        if (index % 4 === 3){
            body.replaceText('{{First Name3}}', row[1]);
            body.replaceText('{{Last Name3}}', row[2]);
            body.replaceText('{{Address3}}', row[3]);
            body.replaceText('{{City3}}', row[4]);
            body.replaceText('{{State3}}', row[5]);
            body.replaceText('{{Zip3}}', row[6]);
        }

        if (index % 4 === 0){
            body.replaceText('{{First Name4}}', row[1]);
            body.replaceText('{{Last Name4}}', row[2]);
            body.replaceText('{{Address4}}', row[3]);
            body.replaceText('{{City4}}', row[4]);
            body.replaceText('{{State4}}', row[5]);
            body.replaceText('{{Zip4}}', row[6]);

            *** want to add another page to the doc here and add another set of 4 template fields and then continue loop ***

        }    
});

doc.saveAndClose();
```

}

Comment: Please include your partially working code for better understanding.

Comment: what does your source sheet look like?